# C 'typdef string' Function Error

Tags: c

I am using C in my Errors.h file, and am using the `typedef` method to create a string called error. However, my compiler (CodeBlocks) highlights an error on that line. Is there something wrong with doing `typedef string`?

```
#ifndef ERRORS_H
#define ERRORS_H

typedef signed int ERROR_NUM;
typedef string ERROR; /** Error Here **/

#endif
```

EDIT:

```
typedef char[] ERROR;
```

Comment: What type is `string`?

Comment: @H2CO3 - I tried `std::string` and it didn't work either

Comment: I don't think `C` has `string` type.

Comment: @user2976089 And you're surprised? Now are you writing C or C++ code?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up C and C++. C does not have strings, just char arrays. Also, why exactly are you using typedefs here in the first place? `int` and `const char *` for error codes/strings is perfectly fine and what other people expect.

Answer (score 1):

String is a not a type in C. You should probably use `char *` or `const char *`. 
Change the line which causes the error to :

```
typedef const char * ERROR;
```